# How do i make my Inkwell onhover work on my menu items?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create an onHover effect on my navigation menu, my approach was to create boolean list as long as my navigation menu items and with initial false values, then when a menu item is hovered change the color, my problem is the value parameter from the inkwell onhover function is printing out the right value to console but it's not affecting my menu item color, any suggestions? When i run it, it remains the color red with the onhover having no effect

```
 final List hover = [false, false, false, false, false];

       InkWell(
                    onHover: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        value ? hover[1] = true : hover[1] = false;
                      });
                    },
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Text('Org Chart',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: hover[1] ? Colors.black : Colors.red))),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have the `hover` variable inside build method? Make sure it is correct state variable of StatefulWidget. I would also recommend removing the `final` annotation since you want to change it on hover.
Also you can simplify your code like this:

```
setState(() {
  hover[1] = value;
});
```

Comment: Yes, cant belive i didnt catch that, the Boolean list was in the build function so it kept creating the list on build, added it to the stateful class above